$s^2 + 1$ has no prime factors $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$?
$s^2 + 1$ is the squared length of a vector in a square lattice for every integer $s$. The number of integer
solutions in $a, b$ for $a^2 + b^2 = s^2 + 1$ is of course $> 0$, e.g. $a = s, b = 1$ is a solution.
A lemma to Jacobis theorem about the number of solutions of $a^2 + b^2 = n$ with $n \equiv 1 \mod 4$ states,
that in the factorization of $n$ every prime factor with $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$ of $n = s^2 + 1$ has to appear with
an even exponent. A search up to $s = 10^6$ shows: no prime factors  $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$.
Is this true for all $s$ and why?

$a^2+b^2$ is congruent to $0,1,2$ $mod 4$

This question is similar to: Argument for why $a^2 + 1$ is never divisible by a $3 \mod 4$ integer. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search.

You are indeed correct that $s^2+1$ cannot have a prime factor $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$. Suppose the contrary, that $s^2+1$ does have such a prime factor $p=4k+3$. Then $$s^2+1\equiv 0\pmod p.$$ However this means that $-1\in QR_p$ (i.e. $-1$ a quadratic residue modulo $p$) and this is easily seen to be false. For example, using quadratic reciprocity we know that $$\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=-1.$$

That is not usually called quadratic reciprocity, but is often called one of the "auxiliary laws" coming with quadratic reciprocity. It is also much easier to prove than QR itself: if there existed $x \in \mathbb F_p$ with $x^2=-1$, then $x$ would have order $4$ in the group $\mathbb F_{p}^{\times}$, but this group has order $p-1$, which is not divisible by $4$, contradiction.

It can be called a supplement to quadratic reciprocity

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

The given statement is equivalent to proving that all odd primes dividing $s^2+1$ are $1$ mod $4$. Now, consider an odd prime $p\mid s^2+1$. We have $s^2\equiv -1\pmod p$, which means $s^4\equiv 1\pmod p$, so $\mathrm{ord}_p(s)=4$ (where $\mathrm{ord}$ refers to multiplicative order). But since $s^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ by Fermat's Little Theorem, we must have $4=\mathrm{ord}_p(s)\mid p-1$, or $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$.
We can actually prove a stronger statement:
Claim: If a prime $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$ satisfies $p\mid a^2+b^2$, then $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$.
Proof. Assume not for the sake of contradiction. WLOG let $p\nmid b$. This means $b$ is invertible, so we can rewrite $a^2+b^2\equiv 0\pmod p$ as $(ab^{-1})^2+1\equiv 0\pmod p$. The same proof follows as before with $s=ab^{-1}$.
Note: This is actually a weaker converse of Fermat's Christmas Theorem.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
